# Can S3 lifecycle action have pre-conditions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a AWS data pipeline activity that reads 2 data files that is received in an incoming bucket from an external system on daily basis. The data pipeline will import these data to a database. Once the data pipeline activity has ended processing I want to move these 2 files to an archived bucket location automatically but this should happen only if the data pipeline has successfully completed. Can I do this file move based on such a pre-condition? And how can I schedule the S3 move?

Comment: How can you tell that the import has completed successfully? Do you ever get partial or corrupted or malformed files?

Comment: Data pipeline activities has a status and last run date/time. Want to find whether I could check that and then do the file move.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a file to an intermediate S3 bucket when the data pipeline execution completes successfully. And, configure a lambda function to get triggered based on the intermediate bucket's event, which can copy the files from source to destination bucket. But, you need to see if lambda executions can handle your file sizes and processing times. If you run into limitations, think about options of using SQS or SNS. A client can be written to process SQS messages or have an endpoint where SNS notifications can be received. On receiving the message, client can copy the files from source to dest bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dependent activity on the import to database activity which does the copy. Make sure the dependent activity is set to cascade failed so it will fail if the import fails.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-manage-cascade-failandrerun.html